# How to directly RUN a function inside a controller class via cron?

Tags: magento, cron

In magento i tried to setup cron as following.

```
   <crontab>    
            <jobs>
                <inchoo_birthday_send>
                    <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                </inchoo_birthday_send>
            </jobs>
    </crontab>
```

Here it calls model but how can i directly call a function inside the controller. For example

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Inchoo_BirthdayController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{


    public function sendAction($strFname)
    {
        // this has to be called from cron in magento.
    }


}
```

How i can directly call the **sendAction** action function inside the above controller from cron. In other words how this sendAction initiated from cron directly. I have to run the conroller function directly instead of model.

Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should treat this class as ordinary model.

```
$observer = Mage::getModel('birthday/observer');
$observer->sendBirthayEmail();
```

Hope this is what You need.

**Edit**

```
$curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
$curl->setConfig(array('timeout'   => 20));
$curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
$curl->read(); //or without this line
```

This should do the trick, if You want more info, please see content of `Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl` class.

If You will only invoke one time `sendAction` inside cron model, then it's ok...

But i suggest to use cron itself, because it is more efficient rather than using Curl multiple times.

Comment: Hi, Please check my updated question. Exactly this is what i have to do. Have to run the controller function daily(Its generating 1000's of pdf's daily). Please help me

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong :) if you need to call a controller with all dispatchers and events you should use wget or curl to call your action. If you don't need all events and dispatchers to fire then your method is just in wrong place

Comment: If so then should i login into admin using curl and then call the exact url. Is thats the correct way to do it?

Comment: no i guess putting this method to block or model would be a ton easier to handle

Comment: Hi, Please check my updated question. Exactly this is what i have to do. Have to run the controller function daily(Its generating 1000's of pdf's daily). Please help me

Comment: you are still doing it wrong, you try to cron schedule a model class but instead your class is a controller one, copy&paste this method to separate observer method and call it that way.